# Using a Query, Joining 4 tables in Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dao

Currently i'm using PostgreSQL database in my Spring MVC web application. I'm able to get the values when i execute the query in `PgAdmin` tool.
In my query, I'm trying to join 4 tables and get the values.
My query is:

```
SELECT (s.school_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username, u.email, p.plan_name, s.start_date, s.end_date, s.subscription_price, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school_user t WHERE t.user_type = 'T' and t.school_id = s.school_id), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school_user t WHERE t.user_type = 'A' and t.school_id = s.school_id), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school_user t WHERE t.user_type = 'S' and t.school_id = s.school_id)) FROM school s inner join user u on s.user_created = u.user_id inner join plan p on s.current_plan = p.plan_Id where s.application_id = 30 and s.site_id = 42;
```

When I use this same query in my Dao method, I'm getting error like:

> No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

**Code used in dao method:**

```
public List<Object[]> getInformationValues(int applicationId, int siteId) throws HibernateException {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT (s.school_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username, u.email, p.plan_name, s.start_date, s.end_date, s.subscription_price, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school_user t WHERE t.user_type = 'T' and t.school_id = s.school_id), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school_user t WHERE t.user_type = 'A' and t.school_id = s.school_id), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school_user t WHERE t.user_type = 'S' and t.school_id = s.school_id)) FROM school s inner join user u on (s.user_created = u.user_id) inner join plan p on (s.current_plan = p.plan_Id) where s.application_id = :applicationId and s.site_id = :siteId") .setParameter("applicationId", applicationId) .setParameter("siteId", siteId);
    List<Object[]> results = query.list();
    return results;
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the code of `getCurrentSession` method and your project dependencies?